# How to create Bitmap for a specific source

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this line:

```
Bitmap tmpSource = new Bitmap("../Resources/logo2013.jpg");
```

But it launces me this exception:

```
Parameter is not valid.
```

The source exists. The `.jpg` property is set to `Resource`. What I am doing wrong???

**Note:**

I tried this before:

```
string uri = @"..\Resources\logo2013.png";
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(uri);
```

this returns this string value:

```
"..\\Resources\\logo2013.jpg"
```

but it also fails...

Comment: just in case, have you tried to pass a full absolute path of your jpg file? something like @'C:\\Temp\logo2013.jpg'... would it work?

Comment: Does it have to be in C:?? Because I need it to be embeded on the project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass *relative* path to the `Bitmap` ctor "../Resources/logo2013.jpg". You can use different [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class methods to obtain complete(exact) path to image you're going to load.

Comment: Don't think ful path is enough, you have to Combine the path of your executable with this relative one... Use Path.Combine(full, "..\Resources\logo2013.jpg").